# ReactJS: React Component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ContactList.js

```
    var React = require('react');
    var Contact = require('./contact.js');

    var ContactList = React.createClass({
         render: function() {
           return(
               <div>
                  <h3>Contacts</h3>
                  <table className="table table-striped">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Number</th>
                           <th>Email</th>
                           <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                        <tbody>
                              {
                                this.props.contacts.map(function(contact, index) {
                                  <Contact contact={contact} key={index} />
                                })
                              }
                        </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
           )
        }
```

Contact.js

```
var React = require('react');

var Contact = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return(
         <tr>
          <td>{this.props.contact.name}</td>
          <td>{this.props.contact.phone}</td>
          <td>{this.props.contact.email}</td>
         </tr> 
      )
  }    
})

module.exports = Contact;
```

Basically, i am able to get the contacts data from firebase in console but i want to display all the contacts i saved in the table. Behind the scenes, there is react-flux setup. State 'contacts' is basically an object inside an array, when i go to react tools, i can't see Contact component there, also if i try to `console.log` something to verify nothing works in Contact component, it seems like props is not passing to Contact component, also sometimes i get
`[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.` don't know whether it is because of this.

Can somebody explain me what is wrong ? Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: You need to `return` the component within the `map` function

Comment: Damn !!!!, how did i forget that, thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to send props to ContactList.js i.e, the response.data that you get after hitting firebase.
Something like this:-

```
React.render(<ContactList contacts= 'your response object' />);
```

Check whether your passing or not.

To solve it more easily you can use React.Component ,

ContactList.js

```
 import React from 'react';
    import Contact from './contact'

       class ContactList extends React.Component {
         {contacts}=this.props;
             render(){
               return(
                   <div>
                      <h3>Contacts</h3>
                      <table className="table table-striped">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Number</th>
                               <th>Email</th>
                               <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                  {
                                    contacts.map(function(contact, index) {
                                      <Contact contact={contact} key={index} />
                                    })
                                  }
                            </tbody>
                      </table>
                   </div>
               )
            }
        }
export default ContactList
```

Contact.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Contact extends React.Compponet{
{contact}=this.props;
  render() {
      return(
         <tr>
          <td>{contact.name}</td>
          <td>{contact.phone}</td>
          <td>{contact.email}</td>
         </tr> 
      )
  }    
}

export default Contact
```

You have to pass the props to the ContactList class which would internally pass it to Contact.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the `Contact` component inside the `ContactList` component like this:

```
this.props.contacts.map(function(contact, index) {
        return <Contact contact={contact} key={index} />
    })
```

or, you can use arrow function:

```
this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => <Contact contact={contact} key={index} />)
```